# How to use SkiaSharp.Views.UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, skiasharp

Is any one know how to use SKXamlCanvas in SkiaSharp.Views.UWP namespace?

I found information just about SkiaSharp.Views.Forms and SKCanvasView.

In official website we have
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/SkiaSharp.Views.UWP/

But nuget did not know anything about UWP. Nuget have packages only for Forms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the [UWP sample](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/tree/13b699c9fcb4e2c2690cb6327e4b6a59c44b4a57/samples/Basic/UWP/SkiaSharpSample) in the SkiaSharp repository on GitHub.

They are using the `Canvas` like this:

```
<Page
    x:Class="SkiaSharpSample.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:SkiaSharpSample"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:skia="using:SkiaSharp.Views.UWP"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <skia:SKXamlCanvas PaintSurface="OnPaintSurface" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

The important thing here is to import the `SkiaSharp.Views.UWP` namespace using `xmlns` attribute so that you can use it in XAML.

The namespace itself should be available after you install the [`SkiaSharp.Views` NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SkiaSharp.Views/) into your UWP project. Please note, that you can access the `SKXamlCanvas` only from the UWP project, not from a shared class library.

In case you use SkiaSharp.Forms, things are a bit different. You don't use `SKXamlCanvas` directly. Instead the library uses `SkiaSharp.Views.Forms.SKCanvasView` in the shared library and then uses Xamarin.Forms custom renderer to render this view as `SKXamlCanvas` on UWP (see the [source code here](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/blob/055ef8c9106c7d344e5c9cab007207dffbdca8d9/source/SkiaSharp.Views.Forms/SkiaSharp.Views.Forms.UWP/SKCanvasViewRenderer.cs)). Basically you shouldn't have to use `SKXamlCanvas` directly and use `SKCanvasView` instead.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what was needed.

Comment: Glad it helped :-) . Happy coding!